# Subset of a closed set cannot be open relative to a superset

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, metric-spaces

Take $E \subset Y \subset X$, where $X$ is a metric space. Assume that $Y$ is closed relative to $X$. Then $E$ is not open relative to $X$.

Is this proposition true? It seems so to me (but I am still moving my first steps in real analysis/basic topology).

Thanks!

Comment: What does “standard metric” mean in this context?

Comment: How about $Y=X$ and $E=\emptyset$?

Comment: Ok, I meant proper subsets.

Comment: I also edited, eliminating "standard metric"

Comment: X = R, Y = [0,1], E = (0,1) is counter example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As it stands, this is not true. Consider $X:= \mathbb{R}$ and $Y := [0,1]$ and $E:= (0,1)$. Then we have $Y$ is closed in $X$ since it is the complement of the open set $(- \infty, 0) \cup (1, \infty)$, but $E$ is open in $X$.

I'm not sure if there are reasonable assumptions under which your claim could be true.

Comment: Thanks. No, it was only this simple intuition around which I wanted to get clarity. It's clear that my intuition was wrong.